# Filtering data according to date range mvc4

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, filter

I am filtering data from the database according to the date range.

First Table Card1 : `CardId, Description`. - Keeps record of all the card available Second Table `Registartion1 : RegistartionId, RegisteredDateTime , CardId`. keep data of the time and data a particular card is used.

In my card Controller I have the following code.

```
public ActionResult List(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
          {
              using (var db = new CardDBEntities())
              {
                  var cards = (from c in db.Card1
                               join d in db.Registration1
                               on c.CardId equals d.CardId
                               where d.RegistrationDateTime >= startDate &&
                                     d.RegistrationDateTime <= endDate
                               select new ModelN
                               {
                                   CardId = d.CardId,
                                   Description = c.Description,
                                   RegistrationDateTime = d.RegistrationDateTime
                               }).OrderByDescending(x => x.RegistrationDateTime)
                                .ToList();

                  ViewData["cards"] = cards;

                  return View();
              }
```

My new model is :

```
 public class ModelN
    {

            public int CardId { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public DateTime RegistrationDateTime { get; set; }

    }
```

And in my view I have this :

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#startDate" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#endDate" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
    $("#endDate").datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
          $("#startDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
      }
    });
  });
</script>

<body>

    <label for="startDate">From</label>
    <input type="text" id="startDate" name="from">
    <label for="endDate">to</label>
    <input type="text" id="endDate" name="to">


</body>
```

When I run the program I get this msg :

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'startDate' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult List(System.DateTime, System.DateTime)' in 'CardReader.Controllers.CardController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters
```

How should I fix this problem. I want to choose the date from the datepicker and then filter.

Please Help me. Thank you in advance

Comment: Chances are your datepicker and the culture you're trying to pass through won't be bound. What happens when you turn your `startDate` and `endDate` parameters to `string` instead (in the action parameters)?

Comment: Can we see the code how you're calling to the action method?

Comment: I have only this code that I wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are receiving indicates that no value for the StartDate parameter has been passed to the List action on your controller. Where do you call this action from? Make sure you are passing a value for StartDate and EndDate. For example:

```
@Html.ActionLink("List Cards", "List", "Cards", new { StartDate = DateTime.Today.Date, EndDate = DateTime.Today.Date.AddDays(7) }, null)
```